# How do I write buffers of current tab in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to write all open buffers in current tab only, without touching buffers of other tabs.

Sth like `:wa` command but for only one or current tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want sort of

```
:windo update
```